# How to update ACL access of AWS S3 object?

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I have inserted object in AWS S3 bucket with "public" access. I want to update this object to have "private" access in some rejection workflow.

Tried below and gets executed fine, but file is still accessible.

```
func updateAccessPolicyForObject(filename string, folder string, awsAccess string) (bool, error) {
    _, err := bigS3.PutObjectAclRequest(&s3.PutObjectAclInput{
        ACL:    aws.String("private"),
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(folder + filename),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("Error updating acl of an object: %v", err)
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

Expected output is that:: File should become inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Go person, so I tried to reproduce your situation with the AWS CLI:

- Uploaded a file to an Amazon S3 bucket that does *not* have a Bucket Policy
- Tried accessing the file via anonymous URL (eg `https://my-bucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/foo`): **Access Denied**
- Ran this command:

```sh
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket my-bucket --key foo --acl public-read
```

- Tried accessing the file via anonymous URL: **Success**
- Ran this command:

```sh
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket my-bucket --key foo --acl private
```

- Tried accessing the file via anonymous URL: **Access Denied**

Therefore, the method you describe should be capable of making the object private again. Thus, either the ACL update did not execute, or **some other method is granting access to the object** (eg a Bucket Policy).

Comment: Thank you John, it worked -- _, err := bigS3.PutObjectAcl(&s3.PutObjectAclInput{ACL: aws.String(awsAccess),Bucket: aws.String(bucket),Key: aws.String(folder + filename)})

Comment: what value awsAccess ?